# Rails: Adding values to Activerecord result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-structures, rails-activerecord

Sorry if I used the wrong terminology, I'm still new to rails.

**Problem:** I retrieve an activerecord relation in a variable and I want to add more key/value pairs into each item in the array so they can all be easily accessed in the view. How do I do this?

**Controller**

```
def index
    @rooms = Room.all.reverse
    @sessions = Session.all
    ##returns => [#<Session id: 4,  user_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_token: "", room_session: "", position: 2 ...>], #<Session id: 3, ...>]
    @sessions.map  do |k, v|
      ##Add the room associated with each session & other k/v pairs
    end
    ##want to return => [#<Session id: 4, room: 'Marvin', spaghetti: 'monster' (etc...),  user_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_token: "", room_session: "", position: 2 ...>], #<Session id: 3, ...>]

    end
  end
```

**View**

```
- @sessions.each do |session|
  %tr
    %td= session.topic_id
    %td= session.room
    %td= session.spaghetti
```

**EDIT:**
I would like to able to add arbitrary values like 'spaghetti' => 'monster'
and info from relations such as, Session.room

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the other attributes (besides the room) also activerecord relations or are they arbitrary?  To add rooms, your session.room call from the view should already assign the associated room (assuming each session only has one room...otherwise you'd want to do session.room.first or something like that.)  To avoid N+1, your @session find should be Session.includes(:room).all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated my question above. One quick question, when I do Session.includes(:room).all.to_a it does not include any of the columns in room, but I can do Session.first.room or session.includes(:room).first.room and get the room associated with that session. Any idea how to get it to be part of the original returned array? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the room in the Session find only adds the room to the session during the Session db lookup (for example, if you look at the log, you'll see the room is being found as well.)  You can then access the cached room via the association (i.e., session.room)

If you're looking to add arbitrary items, the best way to do that would be through a method in your model...for example in your Session class:

```
def spaghetti
  "Monster" # or whatever else you wanted spaghetti to be.
end
```

Then you'll be able to access the spaghetti attribute in the view just as you would any other attribute, for example

```
session.spaghetti # => "Monster"
```

Hope that helps.